# Convert any time string to INDIAN time or INDIA time and date (convert string to indian timezone) using Python3

Tags: python-datetime, date-parsing, python-dateutil

I have a simple problem to convert any kind of date time string into INDIAN date time string or you can say convert to Indian timezone but unable to find an exact approach

Answer (score 0):

so here is the exact answer

```
import pytz
from dateutil import parser

IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
tzdate = parser.parse('2019-04-21T10:38:16.000Z')
print(tzdate.astimezone(IST).isoformat())
```

In this first you are importing "pytz" which is python package for getting time zone of any country using string by which I am getting IST in 3rd line.
After that, I parsed the date and time string in the fourth line.
And after implementing all I assign IST as time zone during printing date and time.